# Multiplying n polynomials of degree 1

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, open-problem, polynomials

The problem is to compute the polynomial $(a_1 x + b_1) \times \cdots \times (a_n x + b_n)$. Assume that all coefficients fit in a machine word, i.e. can be manipulated in unit time.

You can do $O(n \log^2 n)$ time by applying FFT in a tree fashion. Can you do $O(n \log n)$?

Comment: Nice question, seems like I've seen something similar in someone's  blog, but I can't remember where it was.

Comment: Minor observation: we know (working over Q, say) the n roots $\alpha_i = -b_i/a_i$, so the problem is equivalent to: Given $\alpha_1, \dots , \alpha_n$, compute the polynomial $(x-\alpha_1)\dots(x-\alpha_n)$. (I guess.)

Comment: Can you give a reference to the $O(n\log^2 n)$ result?

Comment: @turkistany: do divide and conquer. the merge step is a single multiplication on two polys of degree n/2, which can be done in n log n time via FFT. so the overall recurrence is 2T(n/2) + n log n.

Comment: As @Suresh mentioned, it is a simple divide-and-conquer approach. It can be generalized so that n polys may have different degrees $d_i$, in which case you can divide in a Huffman tree fashion. See Strassen: The computational complexity of continued fractions.

Comment: You're talking about computing the coefficients of the polynomial, right?  Is this equivalent to computing the product of $\sqrt{n}$ $\sqrt{n}$-bit integers in time $\tilde O(n \log n)$ (where $\tilde O$ hides sub-logarithmic factors)?

Comment: @Joshua not sure I see the connection

Comment: @Suresh: as far as I can see, the two questions are not *obviously* equivalent.  The connection is that they both can use divide-and-conquer and then the FFT to get time $\tilde O(n \log^2(n))$.  In a sense both questions are asking whether $n$ FFT-based multiplications can be done in the same asymptotic running time as a single such multiplication; I wouldn't be surprised if a positive answer to one implied a positive answer to the other, but again, it's not obvious.

Comment: @Joshua, I'm confused, What does $n$ represent here? Is it the number of bits or is it the number of polynomials?

Comment: Can we compute the convolution of $n$ vectors of constant dimension 2 in time $O(n \log n)$?

Comment: @turkistany, in both cases it is the number of bits.  In the original question, Mihai stipulated that the coefficients fit into a single word, so the number of bits is O(n).  In my question I stipulated $\sqrt{n}$ numbers of $\sqrt{n}$ bits each, for a total of $n$ bits.

Comment: @Joshua: You're correct, but (and I'm about to say something that's nigh-heresy in a theoretical discussion) machine word size probably grows slower than anything else in all of computer science. For any actual machine a $\sqrt(n)$-bit machine word is just a byte. A "don't care" assumption, as in the question, makes plenty of sense; but taking the further step of treating machine words as a "true" $O(n)$-size object seems too impractical to make much sense to me..

Comment: @Daniel: The standard assumption is that a word is O(log n) bits long. This is sometimes generalized to allow words of length w ≥ log n, but even then, the word size w is typically assumed to be O(polylog n).  Word sizes around √n would make a number of things unreasonably easy, thanks to massive bit-level parallelism.  But yes, O(n)-bit words are right out.

Answer (score 7):

Warning: This is not yet a complete answer. If plausibility arguments make you uncomfortable, stop reading.

I will consider a variant where we want to multiply $(x - a_1) \cdot ... \cdot (x - a_n)$ over the complex numbers.

The problem is dual to evaluating a polynomial at n points. We know this can be done cleverly in $O(n \log n)$ time when the points happen to be $n$-th roots of unity. This takes essential advantage of the symmetries of regular polygons that underlie the Fast Fourier Transform. That transform comes in two forms, conventionally called decimation-in-time and decimation-in-frequency. In radix two they rely on a dual pair of symmetries of even-sided regular polygons: the interlocking symmetry (a regular hexagon consists of two interlocking equilateral triangles) and the fan unfolding symmetry (cut a regular hexagon in half and unfold the pieces like fans into equilateral triangles).

From this perspective, it seems highly implausible that an $O(n \log n)$ algorithm would exist for an arbitrary set of $n$ points without special symmetries. It would imply that there is nothing algorithmically exceptional about regular polygons as compared to random sets of points in the complex plane.

Comment: On the other hand, an $\Omega(n\log^2 n)$ lower bound for such a natural problem seems equally implausible!

Comment: True! I wish I had a more definitive answer. It's very interesting.

Comment: Bounty awarded!

Comment: @PerVognsen: Can you give a reference for this point of view re: symmetries of polygons / interlocking symmetry? Or if this is an observation of your own, could you expand on it a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

In computer algebra, this computation is usually referred as computing the *subproduct tree* and is a subroutine of multipoint evaluation and interpolation. See for instance: von zur Gathen, Gerhard. [Modern Computer Algebra](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/modern-computer-algebra/DB3563D4013401734851CF683D2F03F0), 3rd edition, 2013 [chapter 10]. As far as I know, the best known complexity is $O(\mathsf{M}(n)\log n)$ where $\mathsf M(n)$ denotes the cost of multiplying two degree-$n$ polynomials. (This applies over any ring.)

Comment: Is there a matching lower bound or is the lower bound $\Omega(\mathsf{M}(n))$?

Comment: For the original problem, I do not think so. For the subproduct tree used in multipoint evaluation, the output size is $O(n\log n)$ so this gives a lower bound independent from $\mathsf{M}(n)$ (though not larger).

Comment: Believe me when I say that Mihai knew this... but it is good to name the problem, and give references.

Comment: I had not made the connection between the first name and the author of the question...